# CSS: Button border gradient invert when transition on hover

Tags: css, border, transition, gradient

I'm setting this button transition, and I found that the effect I use for other buttons in my web, doesn't work well with this one.
Border colors invert on transition.

I must use gradient background, so change it isn't an option.

```css
#button {
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF,#FFF) padding-box, linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%) border-box;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #000;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 7px 22px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    }
    
#button:hover{
background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%);
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    }
```

```html
<button id="button"> BUTTON </button>
```

Comment: could you pls provide also your html code - you can simply create a snippet so life-view of your previous progress is visible :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hover/focus gradient should be `border-box`:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%) border-box;
```

```css
.myb {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: linear-gradient(#FFF, #FFF) padding-box, linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%) border-box;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #000;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 7px 22px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.myb:hover,
.myb:focus {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%) border-box;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #FFF;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="myb">
    Button
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ngj4xuve/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea of transition where you can play with background-size:

```css
#button {
    background: 
      linear-gradient(#FFF,#FFF) padding-box center, 
      linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%) border-box;
    background-size:100% 100%,auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 7px 22px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    display: block;
    }
    
#button:hover{
    background-size:0 0,auto;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> BUTTON </button>
```

That you can modify by adjusting the size and position:

```css
#button {
    background: 
      linear-gradient(#FFF,#FFF) padding-box left, 
      linear-gradient(to right, blue 0%, green 100%) border-box;
    background-size:100% 100%,auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin: 60px auto 0;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 7px 22px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    display: block;
    }
    
#button:hover{
    background-size:0 100%,auto;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<button id="button"> BUTTON </button>
```

Comment: These are really cool animation! Thank you! But I have this design from the designer, and he doesn't really likes the changes... haha, but I like it ;)